# Problemas al cargar datepicker dentro de un div col-lg-pull de bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, datepicker, jquery-ui, jquery-datepicker

En los input que ingreso fecha, uso datepicker de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" title="" id="fechar">
</div>

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fechar").addClass("datepicker");
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    }
    );
 });
```

Y  me funciona correctamente, mostrando el calendario de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando le añado la clase col-lg-pull-7 al div, es decir si lo dejo de esta forma:

Pierde el estilo, la opciones de cambiar el año y el mes mostrandose de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema cuando uso el pull, hace que pierda tales propiedades, me gustaría encontrar la solución, si alguien sabe algo, se lo agradecería.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

ya lo solucione, le puse en style esto:

```
 #ui-datepicker-div{
z-index:350 !important;
}
```